# move from Activity to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

i have a fragment say `F1` and from there i'm opening an activity say `A1` and after that activity (`A1`) i'm opening other activity (`A2`) and i'm performing some tasks in `A2` now once my task is over in my activity (`A2`) i want to destroy current opened Activities and move back to my fragment `F1`.

this is what i'm trying to get back to my fragment:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, myFragment.class);
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
```

but i'm getting this error :
`Unable to find explicit activity class`

and i know why i'm getting this (cause specified class is not an activity that is a Fragment ) but my question is how can i move back to that fragment ?

Comment: Fragments cannot be started like Activities. An Activity class holds and shows a Fragment. You cannot "go back to a Fragment" outside its parent Activity

Comment: You cannot start a Fragment with intent. myFragment must be Activity/Service not Fragment.

Comment: When your move from `A1` to `A2` call `finish()` before `startActivity()` and then when you want to move back from `A2`, simply call `finish()`

Comment: @cricket_007   i know why , but my question is ***how can i move back to that fragment ?*** there must be way right

Comment: @Ammy i know why , but my question is ***how can i move back to that fragment ?*** there must be way right

Comment: Is A1 holding F1? If so, just call `finish()` from A2. No need to start a whole new Activity

Comment: @remyboys:- you have to add your fragment to One Activity. and Call That activity from Intent.

Comment: @Shaishav but what if user wants to go back from A2 to A1 for making some changes in A1 ??  adding finish will remove the persistency from that Activity right ?

Comment: well its already inside an activity (Main Activity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot start a Fragment with intent. your every fragment will be attached to some activity. Fragments can be replaced or added in activity,

What you can do is : Your fragment F1 is attached to some activity...say A0. So what you can do is like this :

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(context, A0.class);
intent .putExtra("openF2",true)
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0); 
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    finish(); 
    startActivity(intent);
```

then, inside your activity A0's onCreate you can check for which fragment to replace:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
 if(extras!=null && extras.containsKey("openF2"))
  boolean openF2 = extras.getBoolean("openF2");
if(openF2){
  //add or replace fragment F2 in container
 }
}
```

This is just pseudo code. I hope you will understand it.

**Edit:** If you want to move back to that previous fragment, you can explicitly call activity's `onBackPress()` twice to go back to your activity say `A0` which contains the fragment. Not a good idea though.

Answer (score 0):

Put below code in your Activity from which you want to move.

```
btnDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
   Intent intent = new Intent(SelectLocation.this,MainActivity.class);
   intent .putExtra("tag",true);
   finish();
   startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

and put below code inside oncreate methodin your activity in which you have attatched all fragments.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras!=null && extras.containsKey("flag"))
 boolean flag= extras.getBoolean("flag");
   if(flag){
      currentFragment = getOneFragment();
   }
 }
```

this will work properly for you .